# Return object from async activity function Durable extension Azure Function Nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

In an activity function we return something by doing

```
context.done(null, object);
```

to the durable function
where `object` is my target object to sent.

but when i make my activity function async, [i can not use context.done](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#exporting-a-function)

without `context.done` how can i send my desired object from activity function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we only need to return sth to orchestrator function which calls this activity, a simple `return object;` is enough. Bindings are useful once we want to output the result to other services like blob storage, http response and so on.

Then in orchestrator, get the object as usual.

```
var myObject = yield context.df.callActivity(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just return it. That is, where you would have done `context.done(null, object)` use `return object` instead. For multiple output bindings, use object properties as usual. However if you only have a single output binding, you can bind it directly to your return value by setting the binding name in function.json to `$return`, e.g.

```
{
    "bindings": [
        {
            'type': ...,
            'direction': 'out',
            'name': '$return'
        },
        ...
    ],
    ...
}
```

Comment: i don't have to specify a type?

Comment: You do, I just left it unspecified as it will depend on what you're binding to.